# Using Images in TabBarIOS ~ Low Quality, Tint ruins image

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, tabbarios

We're working on an iOS application using react-native. In this application we're making use of the `TabBarIOS` component. We have five tabs that has separate icons for the active tab, the layout of our images is like this:

```
|_images
|__tabbaricons
|___ tab-1-on.png          (35x35)
|___ tab-1-on@2.png        (70x70)
|___ tab-1-on@3.png        (105x105)
|___ tab-1-off.png         (35x35)
|___ tab-1-off@2.png       (70x70)
|___ tab-1-off@3.png       (105x105)
```

In the TabBarIOS component I have the Items decared like so:

```
<TabBarIOS.Item
    selected={currentTab.name === 'profile'}
    icon={require('./images/tabbaricons/profile-off.png')}
    selectedIcon={require('./images/tabbaricons/profile-on.png')}
    renderAsOriginal={true}
    title="" 
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.navigation.gotoTab({
            tabInformation: { name: 'profile', content: '' },
            statusBarStyle: 'light-content'
        })
    }}>
    <Profile navigator={this.props.navigator} navigation={this.props.navigation />
</TabBarIOS.Item>
```

Across the iPhone4s, iPhone5, and iPhone6s+ the icons are all low quality, they are also covered by the gray tint if they're not selected which completely ruins the image. When selected they are covered by the blue default tint. I tried setting the tint color to `transparent` but that made the tab icon invisible when it was active.

This tinting is completely setting us back as setting the icons in the tab bar was one of the things we put off to last, because it should have been overly simple. It's turning out to be one of the larger hassles.

Previously we were using a UIWebView and scaling a 512x512 image down to size for sharpness. I can't tell if these smaller icons are just really low quality, or if the fuzziness is presented by the TabBarIOS component itself.

**EDIT:** Naming issue on Icons was fixed, problem with rending the icons in Color continues even after the use of `renderAsOriginal`

Comment: Can you add image of tab as it appears and TabBarIOS component props you are using.

Comment: @while1, Unfortunately, I cannot due to NDA reasons. I can tell you that they are covered with the gray unselected tintColor and the `tintColor` prop provided in the `TabBar` component.

Answer (score 2):

First for your images, U didn't name them right, it should be:

```
|_images
|__tabbaricons
|___ tab-1-on.png          (35x35)
|___ tab-1-on@2x.png        (70x70)
|___ tab-1-on@3x.png        (105x105)
|___ tab-1-off.png         (35x35)
|___ tab-1-off@2x.png       (70x70)
|___ tab-1-off@3x.png       (105x105)
```

The system took the lower quality and apply it to all retina device which lead to a low quality images.

About the tint color,
try to add this `prop` to the `TabBarIOS.Item`:

```
renderAsOriginal={true};
```

Please be aware of the fact that the text under the icon of the `TabBar` will be effected only via the `tintColor` so u need to manage the icon as u want for `selected` and `unSelected` as well as the `tintColor` for `selected` and `unSelected`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out about the image name, I completely missed that, as you can see I already have `renderAsOriginal={true}` in my props as demonstrated in the question. The tintColor manages the entire icon color. The title is set to `""` which means theres no text at the bottom. On the documentation it shows only `icon` and `selectedIcon` as well as just `tintColor`, could you provide an example using the images alone without any tint on the images? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios-item.html

Comment: I should also add that `renderAsOriginal` has no effect on the display whatsoever, and that the tint is still applied to the Icon. The entire Icon gets bolded out with Color.

Comment: **NOTE:** renderAsOriginal is only not working on iPhone5

Comment: So, the images are still color tinting?

Comment: Correct, I've opened an issue at GitHub  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9965